# What programming language is this code from?

Tags: sql

I am looking at some SQL code:

```
txtUserId = getRequestString("UserId");
txtSQL = "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE UserId = " + txtUserId;
```

I know in php it uses $_GET or $_POST to retrieve the values entered in a form so I am just wondering what is the language the first statement is written in that is retrieving the values?

Comment: Looks like JavaScript.

Comment: Looks like it could be asp?

Comment: @JonTout asp is not a language. You may be referring to one of two frameworks/engines - ASP.NET or ASP Classic. Within both of those, several languages are supported. Did you have a particular one in mind?

Comment: ASP.NET, this example is taken from here: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp

Comment: Denoc, it could be JavaScript, or possibly C#, or Java, or even something else - lots of languages share similar syntax, and this is some quite basic syntax. Where exactly are you seeing this code? That might give us a clue. If it's in a file, does the filename have an extension e.g. .js or .cs or something?

Comment: Since the lines end in a semicolon, that rules out VB.  To me, the use of Hungarian notation suggests that it's C#.

Comment: @Duston since C# is strongly typed, there's generally no need for hungarian notation. Certainly none of the C# I write or see on a regular basis uses it. You may well be right about the language, as Jordan suggests, but I wouldn't say the hungarian was a good clue

Comment: I agree, since c# is strongly typed, Hungarian isn't necessary and has fallen into disfavor, but I do see some code like this, particularly in legacy applications.  Old habits die hard.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to answer this definitively.  No, not the language question, but the actual, important part of that code snippet.

***Do Not Open Yourself To SQL Injection Attacks.***

That code puts in the text contents of UserId directly into the SQL statement.  Which means that someone can enter something like:

```
UserId=-1 or (1=1)
```

... and get the entire table.  Or:

```
UserId=-1; NewSQLStatementStartsHere
```

... and start running malicious SQL statements on your server.

**Never inject raw values into SQL.**  Always use parameterized values.  SQL Injection Attack is still the #1 cause of security vulnerabilities in software.